# Best conditional approach in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Which one of the following is the best approach?

```
{!isActive? (
  <Button
    onClick={activateJob}
    className={styles.button}
    color="primary"
    variant="contained"
  >
    <Icon style={{marginRight: 5}}>unarchive</Icon> Restore
  </Button>
):(
  <Button
    onClick={deactivateJob}
    className={styles.button}
    color="primary"
    variant="contained"
  >
    <Icon style={{marginRight: 5}}>archive</Icon> Archive
  </Button>
)}
```

OR

```
<Button
  onClick={!isActive? activateJob : deactivateJob}
  className={styles.button}
  color="primary"
  variant="contained"
>
  <Icon style={{marginRight: 5}}>{!isActive ? 'unarchive' : 'archive' }</Icon>
  {!isActive ? 'Restore' : 'Archive'}
</Button>
```

We have to repeat the same code in the first case while we have to check conditions in many places.
I am using the first approach now.

Answer (score 3):

The second approach is much better because it's more scalable and maintainable:

#### Maintainable

Let's say in future you wish to add more props and/or change existing props.
For example, adding property `onHover` and changing `color` to `secondary`.

On second example you edit it in one place:

```
<Button
  ...
  color="secondary"
  onHover={onHover}
>
  ...
</Button>;
```

While on first example you need to repeat code for every component in the condition, where a common mistake will be missing some property for a specific component.

#### Scalability

Let's say in future you adding more complicated conditions.

On second example you target the specific prop:

```
<Button
  ...
  onClick={!isActive && isLogged ? activateJob : deactivateJob}
>
  <Iconn>
    {!isActive && !isOpen ? "unarchive" : "archive"}
  </Icon>
  ...
</Button>;
```

While on second example it may become a huge switch case.

Something like:

```
!isActive && isLogged && !isOpen ? (
  <Button ... />
) : !isActive && !isLogged && isOpen ? (
  <Button ... />
) : (
  <Button ... />
);
```